# AWS Amplify searchable field by geo distance (location)

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, graphql, aws-amplify

I'm developing an application that will allow users to search for other users by ordering them by geo location.

According to the information found on the internet, to do this on amplify I have to perform the following steps:

- create an elastic search mapping, indicating the type 'geo_point' on the lastPosition attribute (I would like to define it once in the project file and not at each build in the elastic search console)
- create a custom query and a custom vtl resolver and set the sort by lastPosition (of type '_geo_distance') in it.

But I don't understand how to do these 2 steps, so I need some suggestion :(.

```
// my schema.graphql
   type User
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{allow: owner}, {allow: private, operations: [read]}])
  @searchable {
  // ...other fields
  id: ID!
  lastPosition: Position
  positionUpdatedAt: AWSDateTime
}

type Position {
  lat: Float!
  lon: Float!
}
```

```
// my custom searchUsers query in graphql/custom_queries.ts
export const searchUsersNearby = /* GraphQL */ `
  query SearchUsersNearby(
    $filter: SearchableUserFilterInput
    $sort: [SearchableUserSortInput]
    $location: PositionInput // current user position that i need to use in vtl resolver to sort users by distance, 
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
    $from: Int
    $aggregates: [SearchableUserAggregationInput]
  ) {
    searchUsersNearby(
      filter: $filter
      sort: $sort
      limit: $limit
      nextToken: $nextToken
      from: $from
      aggregates: $aggregates
    ) {
      items {
        id
        // ...other fields
        lastPosition
        positionUpdatedAt
        createdAt
        updatedAt
        owner
      }
      nextToken
      total
      aggregateItems {
        name
        result {
          ... on SearchableAggregateScalarResult {
            value
          }
          ... on SearchableAggregateBucketResult {
            buckets {
              key
              doc_count
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

I use amplify v8.1.0 with transformer v2.

Thank you guys

Comment: I am stuck here, did you make a bit of progress plz.?